# Overriding get_absolute_url from a model for the sitemap

Tags: django, models, subclassing, sitemap.xml

Hey i have a model that can be accesed through 2 different urls(depending on the domain). And i use them like this in views and templates without problems.

When building the sitemap the get_absolute_url should not return the same so i thought: i can subclass the model and override the get_absolute_url method:

```
class FanpitConcert(BandtasticConcert):
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('event_checkout',(),{'artist_slug':self.slug_name,
                                     'year': self.get_date().year,
                                     'month': self.get_date().month,
                                     'day': self.get_date().day,
                                    })
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And then use this subclassed model for the sitemap class

```
class ConcertsSiteMap(Sitemap):
    def items(self):
        return FanpitConcert.objects.all().filter(app='Fanpit')
```

But when i access /sitemap.xml django still calling the get_absolute_url from the original model

Is there any dark magic django is doing here? or Am i missing something obvious?

UPDATE

I tried removing the abstract = True part and went with
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'same_table_as_base_model'

But now django complains about not finding columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of abstraction, it would be better to use proxy models in this case.

So the subclassed models would have

```
class Meta:
    proxy = True
```

More info on proxy models [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

Comment: I can't make the base model abstract because it is used in many relationships and i get "which has either not been installed or is abstract." Errors for those relationships.
And the trick to get Meta doesnt work :( i get 'BandtasticConcert' has no attribute 'Meta' even thou i have it defined on the model.

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba Try making the subclassed models into proxies. Set `proxy=True` in their `Meta` class and remove the abstraction completely. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for more info.

Comment: thats the answer, thanks! can you put it in answer form so i can mark it as such?